# Focus or Highlight on Sidebar Navigation Menu in Mobile View

Tags: jquery, magento, accessibility, navbar

I am new to jquery, I have a smartwave porto theme in magento 2.4, I have an accessibility issue when trigger on menu in mobile view. I want to focus on an open area (i.e. Nav Menu). Subject to that, I want to highlight through opened nav menu through keyboard's tab button.

Till now, I have achieved to trigger the menu on click through keycode, but I am unable to go through to the main opened menu through keyboard (using TAB button). Expected is to go through open menu using keyboard on clicking / trigger the menu. Here is the code for that

```
require([
      'jquery'
    ], function ($) {
      $(".nav-toggle").keypress(function(e) {
        if ((e.which == 13) || (e.which == 32)) {
          $(e.target).trigger('click');
          //$(e.target).show().focus().click();
        }
      });
    });
```

**Updated with HTML**

HTML for nav-toggle

```
<span data-action="toggle-nav" class="action nav-toggle" tabindex="0"><span>Toggle Nav</span></span>
```

Opened nav-toggle which needs to be focused

```
<div class="section-item-title nav-sections-item-title active" data-role="collapsible" role="tab" data-collapsible="true" aria-controls="store.menu" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0">
    <a class="nav-sections-item-switch" data-toggle="switch" href="#store.menu">Menu</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to _simulate_ the press of the tab key to simulate tab on touch screens? Could you share your HTML please? A [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be great to help you better

Comment: Andy, I have updated the post with HTML

Comment: Thanks, but you didn’t answer to my question. I still don’t get what you are trying to do. You have a nav-toggle thing, but then again a Link that reads Menu, wrapped in an element that  I’m sorry but there are so many things wrong with the aria attributes, I don’t know where to start. Maybe have a look at [the Disclosure pattern from the ARIA Practices Guidelines](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/disclosure/). Beware also of ARIA Rule #1: Use semantic HTML elements where you can, in your case that would be `<button>`